# Creating a list out of object attributes in Python

Tags: python

Really simple question here.  After ben is created, is there anyway I can call ben[0] to call name and ben[1] to call age?

i'm wondering if there is a way to access these attributes as a list.

```
class People():
    def __init__(self, name, age):

ben=People("ben", "10")
```

Comment: That entirely depends on what the rest of your class definition and the init method says...

Comment: It is more logical to use attributes `ben.name` and `ben.age`. If you insist on using indexing, you should implement [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) on the class.

Comment: @Ben: Not many 10-year-olds have thousands of rep points; nice job. :)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're trying to build a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> import collections
>>> People = collections.namedtuple('People', 'name age')
>>> ben = People("ben", 10)
>>> ben.name
'ben'
>>> ben[0]
'ben'
```

If you want additional functionality in your class beyond just having attributes, you can just inherit from the `namedtuple` instead of using it directly:

```
>>> class People(collections.namedtuple('People', 'name age')):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return self.name.title() + '!'
>>> ben = People("ben", 10)
>>> print(ben)
Ben!
>>> ben
People(name='ben', age=10)
>>> ben.name
'ben'
>>> ben[0]
'ben'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class People(object):     
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.stuff = [name,age]
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        return self.stuff[arg]
```

and here it is

```
>>> b = People("ben",10)
>>> b[0]
'ben'
>>> b[1]
10
>>>
```

you could also do something like

```
class People(object):     
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.stuff = {'name':name,'age':age}
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        return self.stuff[arg]

b = People("asd",10)
b['age']
b['name']
```

Comment: no `__getitem__` is called when you access it with square brackets ... `__init__` creates a list

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do with your class is impossible, because its attributes have no inherent order, because they're stored in a dict, so there is no reasonable way to map `ben[0]` to `ben.name` instead of to `ben.age`.

But you can modify the class in a few different ways to make it reasonable:

- Pick an order and store it in a list (e.g., in a class attribute). Then, your `__getitem__` just calls `getattr(self, self._fields[index])`.
- Pick an order that you can define programmatically (e.g., sorted order).
- Use a metaclass to make your class store its attributes in an `OrderedDict`, in which case the order in which you assign them in `__init__` is their order. So it's just `self.__dict__.values()[index]`.
- Use `__slots__` instead of a dict for your attributes.

If you look at the source for [`collections.namedtuple`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l302), you can see that it's using a combination of these: there's a class attribute named `_fields` to store the field names, while the field values are stored in the tuple that it inherits from, and it then defines `__dict__` as a `@property` that puts them together an `OrderedDict` on the fly. This is probably far more clever than you need to be. And, if you *do* need to be this clever, just use or inherit from a `namedtuple` in the first place.